# Ubuntu 17.10 natural scrolling

Tags: 17.10

I have just updated from Ubuntu 17.04. Natural scrolling was not activated, so I turned it on in Settings -> Devices -> Mouse & Touch-pad.
But still not working... What can I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I followed advice from answers to the queston [How to enable natural scrolling with mouse in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904684/how-to-enable-natural-scrolling-with-mouse-in-17-04). In my case removing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and restarting did the trick:

`sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: In case you want to keep using the synaptics driver: `synclient VertScrollDelta=-108 HorizScrollDelta=-108` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working on mine. Credits to [@pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947779/touchpad-double-tap-and-two-finger-scroll-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-04#comment1507820_947782) and [Antonio Kordic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947779/touchpad-double-tap-and-two-finger-scroll-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-04#comment1507817_947782) for getting me to the correct solution: mine works with edge scrolling.

And is has nothing to do with libinput. The gsetting the settings use seems to be wrong initially(!). This was it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled true
```

Even weirder: changing "edge scrolling" in settings->mouse now ALSO works. And turning "natural scrolling" off now also reverses the direction. I do not get why this now works but it works for me ;)

Comment: It tells me:   "property 'libinput Scroll Method Enabled' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format"

Comment: @MatiasHaeussler try the full edit I just did ;)

Answer (score -1):

Add on `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` file the next line:

`Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
-->     Option "Tapping" "true"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection`

This line without the arrow:

-->  `Option "Tapping" "true"`

Next step should either reboot (did myself) or restart X server, it seems is working for me!!

Comment: Tapping should be something else than natural scrolling(?)

Comment: It should be `Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"`. And it should be below `Driver "libinput"`

Comment: After add tapping and reboot could enable and disable scrolling on configuration.  yes, it works for me as  I said!! Took from here https://askubuntu.com/questions/947779/touchpad-double-tap-and-two-finger-scroll-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-04#947782     ... it is what it is!!!

Comment: Sorry @Pilot6. That did work in 17.04 for me but now with wayland ... nope. I followed your instructions from the reply Israel Diaz posted but no scrolling for me :(

Comment: Well, that doesn't work with wayland because there is no X. Wayland should have other configs to pass parameters to libinput. I don't use wayland yet.